# How to export/import a client "WITH ROLES" on Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

Is it possible to export the client role(s) with the client? 
If not, is there a workaround (for example modify manually the JSON before reimporting it ?) or another process that can be automated ?

Comment: Have you found out workaround solution?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I need to copy all necessary settings of the Client to another Keycloak instance, like from dev to prod. I cannot understand, why Keycloak doesn't support this simple scenario. Furthermore - the import fails due to some stupid error, when exporting and importing a client (without any modification in the json) into a fresh Keycloak instance. Pretty buggy.

Comment: still no solution?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can but it's a little tricky.
You have to export entire realm and clean it leaving only this two items:

```json
{
   "roles": {  
    "client": {      
      "<client-name>": [
        {          
          "name": <role-name>,
          "clientRole": true,
           ...
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  "clients": [
    {      
      "clientId": "<client-name>",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

The only thing you cannot do in the same step is importing permissions because import process cannot import permissions based on roles that not exists.